# altool validation failure after upgrading to Sierra/Xcode 8.3

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

I upgraded our build machine that we run Jenkins on to Sierra and updated XCode to 8.3 this week and since then the build script we use to build, archive and upload our app to iTunes has been failing with the following error during the validation phase using altool ...

```
13:59:23 2017-04-04 14:08:51.858 altool[56725:273095] *** Error: (
13:59:23     "Error Domain=ITunesConnectionOperationErrorDomain Code=1095 \"Unable to process app at this time due to a general error\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Unable to process app at this time due to a general error, NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to process app at this time due to a general error, NSLocalizedFailureReason=iTunes Store operation failed.}"
13:59:23 )
```

Yet if I run the same command (below) we're using in the build script within terminal on the same machine it validates the build without error.

```
altool --validate-app -f /(path to my IPA)/(appname).ipa -u me@myworkplace.com -p (password)
```

Similarly, if I use the GUI Application Loader tool it works fine as well. It only errors out when the above command is executed within our build script. Also, the build script has not changed at all, only the OS and the version of XCode we're using. Has anyone else run into this issue? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Same here: `--upload-app` works correctly, but `--validate-app` always returns the general error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up having to delete and reinstall XCode and Application Loader to resolve the issue.

Comment: You can also just delete Application Loader and copy it from XCode.app/Contents/Applications back into /Applications